# go build works fine but go run fails

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, go

I have a few files in the main package under one directory:

main.go
config.go
server.go

When I do: "go build" the program builds perfect and runs fine.
When I do: "go run main.go" it fails.

Output:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:7: undefined: Config
./main.go:8: undefined: Server
```

The symbols that are undefined are structs and they are capitalised so should be exported.

My Go version: go1.1.2 linux/amd64

Comment: What is the `package` for `main.go` and `config.go` with `server.go`? If you are going to run them all three must have `package main`.

Comment: they all three have package main.

Comment: Keep in mind that `go run` is fairly limited. You should be using `go build` to build your package(s) and running it with ./packagename or packagename if it's on your PATH.

Comment: You can build and execute easily without go run:  "go build && ./packagename"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This should work

```
go run main.go config.go server.go
```

[Go run takes a file or files](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) and it complies those and only those files which explains the missing symbols in the original post.

Comment: This indeed works but the wierd thing is that external imports (the ones you put in import()) do work perfectly without me having to specify them on the command line.

Comment: @RoelVanNyen That's not weird at all - since they're imported, the go toolchain knows where to look for them

Comment: Would be great though if the companion packages were imported automatically by go run

Comment: @RoelVanNyen Why didn't you suggest `go run *.go`?

Comment: @RoelVanNyen This seems better -if has no side effects at all. All in all, why to write down each and every thing.

Comment: There is a side effect for me: 
    `$ go run *.go`
    `go run: cannot run *_test.go files (main_test.go)`
There's a discussion around this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695448/golang-run-all-go-files-within-current-directory-through-the-command-line-mul)

Answer (score 40):

You could execute it as:

```
go run .
```

so you don't have to include all files manually.

Answer (score 3):

Good practise would be to create a package for it and run

```
go run ./app
```

Ex. Folder Structure

```
    ├──app/
    |  ├──main.go
    |  ├──config.go
    |  ├──server.go
    ├──bin/
    |  ├──foo.go
    └──pkg/
       └──bar.go
```