# How to run all .go files within current directory through the command line (multi file package)

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I'm a newcomer to Go. I extremely like the language, but I quickly realised that I needed to start dividing my files due to an increase in program size.

`go run main.go` (with main.go having been the file with my main() function)

didn't work and I hit a barrier for a while, because I had no clue how to get my program working.

Some quick searching lead me to the answer of

`go run main.go other.go ..`

where by typing all the files that my `package main` consists of, I could get the programming running. However, this is utterly cumbersome and frustrating to do each time.

I write the following self-answered question in order to prevent others like myself who may again hit this barrier.

Answer (score 115):

Finally we can now use:

```
go run .
```

thanks to: 
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22726#issuecomment-345841019

Comment: But how do I do this when my working directory is not and must not be `.`?

Comment: . is just a placeholder for current directory. You can replace is probably by any other path.

Comment: This happens when the "package main" exist in more than 1 file, then you can't just simply run e.g. "go run main.go" or "go run app.go", you will need to run "go run ." === "go run file1.go file2.go file3.go..." === "go run *.go" 
Thanks for this answer. Great enlightening moment!

Answer (score 76):

As [Nate Finch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/sdeUC2VQjfU/d83BCYTYmzgJ) notes:

> Go run is ... really only meant to be used on very small programs, which generally only need a single file.

Even on unix, `go run *.go` is often not correct. In any project with unit tests (and every project should have unit tests), this will give the error:

```
go run: cannot run *_test.go files (something_test.go)
```

It will also ignore build restrictions, so `_windows.go` files will be compiled (or attempted to be compiled) on Unix, which is not what you want.

There has been a [bit of discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-nuts/%22go$20run%22/golang-nuts/EOi0VAQNA4c/iuMCOulzwecJ) of making `go run` work like the rest of the `go` commands, and there's an open CL for it ([5164](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5164)). It's currently under consideration for Go 1.4. In the meantime, the recommended solution on all platforms is:

```
go build && ./<executable>
```

Answer (score 26):

**Unix related systems**

`go run *.go` will be sufficient in most cases.

Continue to the below method if this causes errors.

**Windows systems** (and in other cases where `go run *.go` doesn't work)

Token expansion doesn't work in the windows command line and hence the above will not work and display an error. `go run *.go` may also not work in OSs in some cases due to current compiler limitations.

In these cases, use

`go build && foo.exe`

where `foo.exe` is the name of the .exe file produced.
If perhaps you have no idea what the name of your executable is, first

`go build` and check the name of the .exe file produced. Afterwards, use the method that includes the file name.

These 2 methods will build and run all the .go files within your current directory with minimum fuss.

Comment: how to run *.go under the folder in subfolder?

Comment: in case you use Windows PowerShell it's: go build; .\foo.exe (instead of && you have ; (point and comma))

Comment: Is there a cross platform way, that `filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))` is not temp directory?

Answer (score 26):

You can run all `.go` files, excluding tests, using this bash construction:

```
go run $(ls -1 *.go | grep -v _test.go)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It solves the problem for *nix developers

Comment: I like this, but the command doesn't play nicely when it's set as an alias. r.sendecky's solution with `shopt` and the `!(...)` works really well.

Answer (score 19):

The best way to do it is to run it like this:

```
go run !(*_test).go
```

It skips all your test files which is exactly what you need to avoid the error.

The other suggestion:

```
go build && ./<executable>
```

is a bit annoying. You have to delete the executable all the time to avoid being marked by git. You can put it in gitignore, of course, but I am lazy and this is an extra step.

Comment: @user1872384 you should run `shopt -s extglob` first to enable the `!(...)` wildcard syntax

Comment: Working well, but just not in bash files for some reasons, I suppose there are some unsupported characters.

Answer (score 8):

If i understand your question right, you need import other code as libraries.

Little example

**./testing/main.go:**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import L "testing/lib"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from main()")
    L.Somefunc()
}
```

**./testing/lib/somelib.go:**

```
package lib

import "fmt"

func Somefunc() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from Somefunc()")
    return
}
```

To launch - `go run main.go`

Comment: This is the right answer for developers on windows. In my case I had to use fully qualified path `import "github.com/abacaj/hello/lib"` and then use it like `sc := new(lib.ServiceControl)`

Answer (score 4):

just use this

```
go run *.go
```

it will work assuming u don't have any test files

Comment: Thats definitely what I was looking for! Thx!

Comment: Will not work on Windows. `CreateFile *.go: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: but now, we can just use go run . :)

Comment: Will not work if there are any test files. Better use `go run .`

Comment: Yes it works on windows. Just use git bash

Answer (score 3):

If you are run in terminal of Vscode on Windows AND without knowledge about workspace, just do like this:

```
go run $(ls *.go)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
go run $(find . -name "*.go" -and -not -name "*_test.go" -maxdepth 1)
```

I use it with an alias to make it easy to run command line apps

```
alias gorun='go run $(find . -name "*.go" -and -not -name "*_test.go" -maxdepth 1)'

$ gorun param1 param2
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows I usually just add a little **test.bat** to all my project directories:

```
go build
.\{project_name}.exe
go clean
```

Works well enough. Replace {project_name} with the name of your executable, of course. And once the executable finishes, the batch script moves on to the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

For peoples attempting to use `go run` combined with `go generate` a solution can be :

```
//go:generate sh -c "go run path/*.go"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows PowerShell and Windows Command Prompt please use the below command:

```
go run .
```

For Git Bash, Linux terminal, or Mac terminal please use the below command:

```
go run *.go
```

Answer (score -1):

For window the following works:
Open cmd and go to the path where your folder exists. Then type the following command and press Enter.

```
go build
```

after this one executable will be created. Then in the command prompt call the executable.
If your executable name is Project.exe then type the following and press Enter:

```
Project.exe
```