# Golang undefined variable

Tags: go, undefined

I have 2 go files:

`/Users/username/go/src/Test/src/main/Test.go`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(SomeVar)
}
```

and file `/Users/username/go/src/Test/src/main/someFile.go`

```
package main

const SomeVar = "someFile"
```

However I am constantly getting compiler error:

> /Users/username/go/src/Test/src/main/Test.go:6: undefined: SomeVar

Can someone explain to me why is `SomeVar` labeled as undefined?

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?  If you ran `go build Test.go`, then it will only consider that one file to be part of the package.

Comment: 1. Use `go build` - go run is really only ideal for simple, single file programs. 2. Don't call the folder 'main'.

Comment: Show your `$GOPATH` please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang "undefined" function declared in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153203/golang-undefined-function-declared-in-another-file)

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
go run Test.go someFile.go
```

Answer (score 11):

[Quote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/sdeUC2VQjfU/d83BCYTYmzgJ):

> I think you're misunderstanding how the go tool works.  You can do "go
>   build" in a directory, and it'll build the whole package (a package is
>   defined as all .go files in a directory).  Same for go install, go
>   test, etc.  Go run is the only one that requires you to specify
>   specific files... it's really only meant to be used on very small
>   programs, which generally only need a single file.

So do:

```
go build && ./program_name
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695709/248296)

Comment: @staticx: It provides an explanation of the error and a solution. It provides an answer to the question.

Comment: Now it does. Your post showed up in the low quality queue.

Comment: This helped me! I was running into this issue trying to run my large program in Gogland. I fixed it by going to the run configurations and switching the project type to directory!

Answer (score 9):

You code is correct:

- `someFile.go` and `Test.go` belong to the same package (`main`)
- `SomeVar` is a `const` declared at top level, so it has a package block scope, namely the `main` package block scope
- as a consequence, `SomeVar` is visible and can be accessed in both files

(if you need to review scoping in Go, please refer to the [Language Specification - Declarations and Scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)).

Why do you get an `undefined` error then?

You probably launched `go build Test.go` or `go run Test.go`, both producing the following output, if launched from `/Users/username/go/src/Test/src/main`:

```
# command-line-arguments
./Test.go:6: undefined: SomeVar
```

You can find the reason here: [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

If you launch `go build` or `go run` with a list of `.go` files, it treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package, i.e., it thinks there are no other pieces of code in the `main` package, hence the error.
The solution is including all the required `.go` files:

```
go build Test.go someFile.go

go run Test.go someFile.go
```

`go build` will also work with no arguments, building all the files it finds in the package as a result:

```
go build
```

**Note 1**: the above commands refer to the local package and, as such, must be launched from the `/Users/username/go/src/Test/src/main` directory

**Note 2**: though other answers already proposed valid solutions, I decided to add a few more details here to help the community, since this is a common question when you start working with Go :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to landing on this page when I had a similar question, I'll include this answer alongside of what has already been stated. If you are using go run you may use:

`go run .` or `go run .*`

This question was also answered on this question

[How to run all .go files within current directory through the command line (multi file package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695448/how-to-run-all-go-files-within-current-directory-through-the-command-line-mult)