# "undefined" function declared in another file?

Tags: go, undefined, func

I'm trying to write a basic go program that calls a function on a different file, but a part of the same package. However, it returns:

```
undefined: NewEmployee
```

Here is the source code:

`main.go`:

```
package main

func main() {
emp := NewEmployee()    
}
```

`employee.go`:

```
package main

type Employee struct {
    name string
    age int
}   

func NewEmployee() *Employee {
    p := &Employee{}
    return p
}

func PrintEmployee (p *Employee)  {
    return "Hello world!"
}
```

Comment: do your files have package statements? What you typed doesn't have a `package x`, also your main package typically only contains a single file, then imports the other pieces it needs

Comment: are you using `go run`? (and see http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: @Crisfole yes the imports in main.go are "flag" and "fmt". Employee.go has no imports and both files are under a package called "main"

Comment: @JimB I tried both go run and go build, to no avail

Comment: @JuanM, my question was is that the **complete** source of `main.go` and `employee.go`? Because all go files are supposed to have a package statement, and I don't see any in yours. See: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackageNames

Comment: The last func of employee.go is wrong (no function name, no return type declared). It is not the problem you ask for, but it shows that there are more problems. Could you post the complete code and the complete error when compiling?

Comment: then show us what your doing! GOPATH, actual code, and how you're invoking the `go` tool.

Comment: %GOPATH% C:\gocode\src

the files Employee.go and main.go are under C:\gocode\src

Comment: Please add the commands you use to compile to your question.

Comment: if you have multiple files then either build with `go build` or `go build a.go b.go`

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Please read ["How to Write Go Code"](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Use `go build` or `go install` within the package directory, or supply an import path for the package. Do not use file arguments for `build` or `install`.

While you can use file arguments for `go run`, you should build a package instead, usually with `go run .`, though you should almost always use `go install`, or `go build`.

Comment: thanks for the input @JimB! I edited the environment variables (I also had forgotten to set GOBIN), moved my files to the correct location, but still when i try go intstall i get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you certain there's no other errors? Your employee.go file can't compile as is. Otherwise, I need to see *exactly* what you're doing. Exact paths, invocation, etc.

Comment: Also running `go run .` -  the period being "this directory"

Comment: @Puran `go run *.go` is a bad idea, because it will break if you have any build constraints or test files.

Answer (score 132):

I just had the same problem in GoLand (which is Intellij IDEA for Go) and worked out a solution. You need to change the `Run kind` from `File` to `Package` or `Directory`. You can choose this from a drop-down if you go into `Run/Edit` Configurations.

Eg: for package `~/go/src/a_package`, use a `Package path` of `a_package` and a `Directory` of `~/go/src/a_package` and `Run kind` of `Package` or `Directory`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Please mention that your answer is about Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I wish this would show up closer to the top by default. This is a really valuable answer.

Comment: This addresses my problem with IDEA.

Comment: Just to clarify, go to the menu and choose `Run` -> `Run...`  -> `Edit Configuration...`  and you will see the `Run kind`. For me the `Directory` solved the issue. The `Package` gave me other errors, thanks.

Answer (score 55):

If you're using `go run`, do `go run *.go`. It will automatically find all go files in the current working directory, compile and then run your main function.

Comment: Are there any downfalls to doing it this way? This seems like the simplest answer to the OPs question.

Comment: A more general solution under Bash: `go run !(*_test).go` -- [Golang: run all .go files within current directory through the command line (multi file package)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479692/86967)

Answer (score 20):

`go run .` will run all of your files. The entry point is the function `main()` which has to be unique to the `main` package.

Another option is to build the binary with `go build` and run it.

Comment: I've been a while to run my old go project and forget how to run. I finally found it with your answer. This should be an upvoted answer!

Answer (score 18):

You can try one of the following:

**Method 1**:

- Assume that your project name is `MyProject`
- Go to your path, run `go build`
- It will create an executable file as your project name ("MyProject")
- Then run the executable using `./MyProject`

You can do both steps at once by typing `go build && ./MyProject`. Go files of the `package main` are compiled to an executable.

**Method 2**:

- Just run `go run *.go`. It won't create any executable but it runs.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call a function from another go file and you are using Goland, then find the option 'Edit configuration' from the Run menu and change the run kind from File to Directory. It clears all the errors and allows you to call functions from other go files.

Answer (score 4):

you should use [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) now, if you are not following [How to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

With go module you don't have to put the code in the $GOPATH/src. it can live in any other location as well.

You can move the code to different directory like /employee, To make it work Just under employee directory initialise the go module

```
go mod init example.com/employee
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a nasty `import "C"` in one of my go files.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem when using goland.
`Need to run as a package`
[image]

The following two ways can be solved.

#### 1

[image]

#### 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with `Go11`, just wanted to share how I did solve it for helping others just in case they run into the same issue.

I had my Go project **outside** `$GOPATH`, so I had to turned on `GO111MODULE=on` without this option turned on, it will give you this issue; even if you you try to build or test the whole `package` or `directory` it won't be solved without `GO111MODULE=on`

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly address the OP's specific issue, I thought I'd chime in with the solution to my "undefined" error: the file with the undefined method had a [build constraint](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) (build tag).

More specifically, I accidentally included a build constraint to remove testing files from my deployed application binary in a utility function file used by my deployed binary. So in the OP's example - if `employee.go` had a build constraints their `go build` command would need to include a `-tags` flag matching the constraint in in order to have the file included.

For more info read this blog post:
https://dave.cheney.net/tag/build-constraints

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to drill down my own MRE for this, so hopefully it will help others, despite being brief:

**This can also occur if your functions / structs are defined in a file that has `import "C"`**, which will be silently ignored if `CGO_ENABLED=0` is in your go environment, leading to you staring at a two file package that somehow is unable to share between themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In GoLand,

- right click a directory
- GoLand will give you the option for build it and run it
- it will also create a run configuration draft for you
- you can save with an option of the upper right dropdown

If you right clic a file, it shows you commands to run, debug, test that file.

If you right clic a directory, it will be the same for that "package", expecting a main.go file inside the directory

Comment: I'm  getting this error in my github actions using goreleaser.

Answer (score -2):

If your source folder is structured /go/src/blog (assuming the name of your source folder is blog).

1. cd /go/src/blog ... (cd inside the folder that has your package)
2. go install
3. blog

That should run all of your files at the same time, instead of you having to list the files manually or "bashing" a method on the command line.

Comment: And here's a digital ocean article too: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-and-install-go-programs