# Go package with multiple files, how to structure

Tags: go, package

Go noob, I cannot seem to figure out how to structure my project with packages. What I want is this:

- I want to create a package, lets say its called Dart.
- I have a file called dart.go with package main and the main function in my project directory.
- I have another file, lets call it functions.go in my project directory with 'package dart' as the first line.
- I just want to call functions from functions.go in main, but cannot figure out how to name the packages to get it to build.
- If I put package dart at the top of functions.go it wont build because it finds packages main and dart. I dont want functions.go 
  to be part of another package, I just want one package and the ability to split the functions in this package into multiple files.
- Is this possible in go, or do I have to make multiple packages?

dart.go

```
package main 

import (
  ...
)  

func main () {
  ...
  // call functions declared in functions.go
  ...
}
```

functions.go

```
package dart  

import (
  ...
)

func Function1() {
  ... 
}

func Function2() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: These issues are covered in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Thanks, I did read this and other resources. The issue for me was that I incorrectly believed 'package main' to be a special declaration used only once per package.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if all you want to do is access functions in a different file, have functions.go also start with `package main` instead of `package dart`. That way, you are working within a single package but with your code divided into multiple files. Make sure they're in the same directory so that they're considered in the same package.

Comment: I think I had the preconceived idea that there could be only one package main declaration per package. Silly, this prevented me from seeing something so simple. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone whose dart.go doesn't seem to have access to Function1 like mine did:
Use `go run .`  instead of `go run dart.go`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695448/how-to-run-all-go-files-within-current-directory-through-the-command-line-mult) explanation

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to create a library then you won't need a main package. However, if you are looking to create a standalone program that runs functions from a different package (`dartlib`) then you'll need a main file.

It would also be a good idea to name your program something different than the library you are calling (*program* `dart` calling *library* `dartlib`)

*Library*

Your library directory structure should look something like the following:

```
dartlib
|
 dartlib.go
```

---

dartlib.go

```
package dartlib

function Hello() string { return "hello!" }
```

This can be imported as the following: 
`"github.com/your_github_username/dartlib"`

---

*Program*

Or, you can store the package within your program directory. In this case the directory structure should look something like the following:

```
dart (you_program_name)
|
 dart.go
 dartlib (package)
 |
  dartlib.go
```

In this case, the library can be imported as the following: 
`"github.com/your_github_username/dart/dartlib"`

---

dart.go

```
package main

import (
 "github.com/your_github_username/dart/dartlib"
 "fmt"
)

helloString := dartlib.Hello()
fmt.Println(helloString)
```

`go build .` at directory root produces the `dart` executable.

`$./dart
 hello!`

For more examples and further explanation see the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library)

Answer (score 4):

As [Wombologist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11529593/wombologist) mentioned, you can split different files under the same package without problem, assuming they share the same `package` definition. The only exception for different package definitions under the same directory is for tests, where the recommended way of defining the package is adding `_test` on it (e.g. `package main_test` or `package dart_test`).

Not sure if it's your case here or if you are just experimenting with the language, but I would add that Go projects are easier to maintain when you group same domain code under packages and share them around, increasing the potential reusability.