# How to call a variable declared on the root package

Tags: go, global-variables

I have a version.go on my root folder(MyPackage).

```
package MyPackage
var (
    Version = "undifened"
    Hash = "undifined"
)
```

And I have second file found on MyPackage/cmd/bootloader/bootloader.go

```
package main
import(
       "MyPackage"
       "fmt"
)

func main() {
     fmt.Println(MyPackage.Version)
}
```

But I am getting`undeclared name: MyPackage` and `"MyPackage" imported but not used as ext` on gotype and i dont know how to fix.

I tried executing this `gotype bootloader.go` and get this.

```
bootloader.go:9:14: undeclared name: MyPackage
bootloader.go:4:2: "MyPackage" imported but not used as ext
```

I will appreciate for any help will come.

Edit: This is not the same with [Golang Global Variable access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038864/golang-global-variable-access) because this will defeat the purpose of that variables, because i don't want to rewrite it on the every main.go. because I want to build the main.go with the `-ldflags` to set the value on the variable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143035/discussion-on-question-by-zer09-how-to-call-a-variable-declared-on-the-root-pack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone have this, doing `go install` on the directory where the main package is, makes the `gotype` stop spitting the message.